# In this Shtar Tena'im (שטר תנאים) the chatan and kallah are represented by their mothers, not fathers, why?

Tags: wedding, legal-documents, engagement-shidduch

I received a שטר תנאים dating 100-130 years ago possibly from Poland, possibly England, written in Hebrew. There are no dates or locations on the document! The chatan and kallah are represented by each of their *mothers* and there is no mention of their fathers. I am unsure of whether their fathers were alive at the time of writing the shtar. If the fathers passed away (or were sent to war that could be an answer). However, I am specifically curious as to whether mothers representing their children on such a document would have been done lechatchila and why.

I asked a Rav who said that it is standard custom to write the fathers name on the shtar (perhaps that is more prevalent nowadays). The signing/writing of the shtar is now done at the engagement or wedding, not separately.

Could there be a reason for only the mothers representing their children on this shtar, assuming that the fathers were alive? I am unfamiliar with the customs of writing a שטר תנאים and don't know how the various customs developed and changed.

Comment: It might be helpful to post a scan or a picture of the shtar

Comment: Maybe their fathers weren't living?